# Boxplot of table using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to plot a boxplot graph with my data, using 'ggplot' in R, but I just can't do it. Can anyone help me out?
The data is like the table below:

```
Paratio  ShapeIdx  FracD   NNDis   Core
-3.00    1.22    0.14    2.71    7.49
-1.80    0.96    0.16    0.00    7.04
-3.00    1.10    0.13    2.71    6.85
-1.80    0.83    0.16    0.00    6.74
-0.18    0.41    0.27    0.00    6.24
-1.66    0.12    0.11    2.37    6.19
-1.07    0.06    0.14    0.00    6.11
-0.32    0.18    0.23    0.00    5.93
-1.16    0.32    0.15    0.00    5.59
-0.94    0.14    0.15    1.96    5.44
-1.13    0.31    0.16    0.00    5.42
-1.35    0.40    0.15    0.00    5.38
-0.53    0.25    0.20    2.08    5.32
-1.96    0.36    0.12    0.00    5.27
-1.09    0.07    0.13    0.00    5.22
-1.35    0.27    0.14    0.00    5.21
-1.25    0.21    0.14    0.00    5.19
-1.02    0.25    0.16    0.00    5.19
-1.28    0.22    0.14    0.00    5.11
-1.44    0.32    0.14    0.00    5.00
```

And what I exactly want is a boxplot of each column, without any relation "column by column".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`ggplot2` requires data in a specific format. Here, you need `x=` and `y=` where `y` will be the values and `x` will be the corresponding column ids. Use `melt` from `reshape2` package to `melt` the data to get the data in this format and then plot.

```
require(reshape2)
ggplot(data = melt(dd), aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable))
```

[image: ggplot2_boxplot]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Really worked... And, one more question: how can I exclude that legend?

Comment: `+ theme(legend.position="none")`